# Free service for push notifications of remote job updates

Tags: python, web-services, push-notification

I frequently have to run some experiments on a remote machine for many hours. Is there a super quick and easy way to have updates pushed to a web service somewhere which will then notify me on my browsers and/or phones, instead of me watching the job manually? I'm on Windows by the way.

Comment: This is definitely not a stackoverflow question

Comment: Sorry but why? I'm asking at this from a code point of view. Could you recommend the proper stackexchange site for it to go to?

Comment: Well, because the question is too general, so the only thing you can get is a tonne of quite useless suggestions, based on personal preferences. I'd recommend superuser.com

Comment: pckben we cant give recomendations for tools, libraries or any software for that matter. If you give us code samples we can help you.